# Add log for keycloak.protect access denied request

Tags: node.js, keycloak

I'm using the (here the [code](https://wjw465150.gitbooks.io/keycloak-documentation/content/securing_apps/topics/oidc/nodejs-adapter.html)):

```
app.get( '/:section/:page', keycloak.protect( protectBySection ), sectionHandler );
```

and in the protectBySection() function, I'm using **winston logger** to log my requests. It works.
If I use a bad token or expire I have got **Access Denied** (it is correct).
My question is: how can I use my log also in Access Denied requests?